# Remove physically image from DOCX using Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.17 to generate docx from template. While working, I replace the blank images with the necessary images, replacing the relationId in CTDrawing with my own id. This leaves unused image files in the document. I would like to remove these images completely.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in the source code of apache poi, I found the best way for myself to replace the image.

```
private boolean replace_image(XWPFDocument docx, String img_to_replace, String img_source)
    {
        try {
            if (!new File(img_source).exists()) 
                return false;
            List<XWPFPictureData> doc_pics = docx.getAllPictures();
            for(XWPFPictureData cur_pic : doc_pics)
            {   
                if (!cur_pic.getFileName().equals(img_to_replace))
                    continue;
                PackagePart pic_package_part = cur_pic.getPackagePart();
                byte [] picbytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(img_source));
                try (OutputStream outputStream = pic_package_part.getOutputStream()){
                    outputStream.write(picbytes);
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        
        return false;
    }
```